# AWK command -drop one column and save with different name with date

Tags: awk

I have this script to separate file for first column and second column

```
awk -F\| 'NR>1 {print > "SEPARATE_COLUMN_"$1"_"$2".csv"}' name_1.csv
```

But I want **to drop the second column after separating the file and include date in the file name**.

Here is the input sample

```
column1|column2|column3
a|b|1
a|b|2
a|d|2
```

The output I want is in new file name SEPARATE_COLUMN_a_b_todaydate.csv

```
column1|column3
a|1
a|2
```

extra notes--I have many files to separate, name_1.csv, name_2.csv and so on
--different files have different number of columns
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F\| 'NR>1 {print > "SEPARATE_COLUMN_"$1"_"$2"_"strftime("%d-%m-%y" ,systime())".csv"}' name_1.csv
```

This uses `awk`'s inbuilt `strftime` function. `%d-%m-%y` is the format of the time to be converted from `systime()` which returns epoch time.

Or you can use: this will use bash to calculate the current date and store it to a variable for later use.

```
awk -v date="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d ")"  -F\| 'NR>1 {print > "SEPARATE_COLUMN_"$1"_"$2"_"date".csv"}'  name_1.csv
```

Comment: I tried your script but it shows function strftime is not defined.

Comment: @kiki ,what is your `awk` version ? mine is `GNU Awk 3.1.7` and it works fine.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you have any idea how to drop column like I said in above? @PS.

Comment: If you want to remove 2nd column then inside awk before print  `'{$2="",.......}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this to elaborate with.

```
awk -F\| 'NR<4{print $1,$3}' OFS=\| file

column1|column3
a|1
a|2
```

Comment: Oh forgot to mention in my question, it is actually to skip 2nd column. I have nth number of columns (almost 100) and want to drop the second column. But, thanks!